# Returning an object of a nested class

Tags: c++, class

I have two classes nested as follows:

```
class A{
    private:
        class B{

        };
    B *object;
}
```

now I want to have a function that can return this object, something like:

```
B& A::get_object(){
    if(object == nullptr)
        object = new B();
    return *object;
}
```

but it says that B does not name a type in get_object(). What have I done wrong, how can I repair it?

The main purpose I'm doing it is that I want to hide the B class in a matter of not allowing to create an object of B in any other way than in a call to A::get_object(). Maybe I should do it another way?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think it needs to be fully qualified. `A::B&`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the return type of the method as `A::B&`.

You can get away without fully scoping the return type in the class's declaration, but *not* in the implementation - which can feel misleading.

Also, as you're returning a reference you'd need to take care that the `B* object` is NEVER null - usually by instatiating it in the constructor and only deleting it in the destuctor, otherwise that method could return a reference to null.

If an object has to live as long as it's parent object, why not put it on the stack - either that or have the method return a `B*`.

Comment: Isnt it taken care of in the get_object() method? I am setting objec to nullptr in the constructor and deleting it in the destructor. Also, how should I disable the possibility to create an object of B class somewhere else? Should I just explicitly declare the constructors & CC with delete keyword?

Comment: It is, but if you put the object on the stack you wouldn't need to take care of it.  If, however, it is an expensive object that might not always be created in a program run, then creating it only when asked for is a valid approach.